# Dump Sqlite 3 field to a text file using PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I've a db (siir_05.db) and some 2 tables in it (sair, siir). I want to save a field in siir table to a text file. I wonder if it is possible.

Comment: Just echo the output and saving via fwrite() would not work ? p.s: yapma bunu işte bunu yapma :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-off operation, it would be easier to use the `sqlite3` command-line tool:

```
sqlite3 siir_05.db "SELECT AField FROM siir;" > ATextFile.txt
```

If you must do this in PHP, it's possible, but there is no predefined helper for this.
You have to write a query for that field, loop over the result, and write all values into the file manually.
(See, e.g., a [file write tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php)).

See the [fetcharray documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) for how to get the values out of the `query` result.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. here's my final code http://sudrap.org/paste/text/198401/ but now I'm getting error: Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\server\htdocs\test2.php on line 17